# Cant add the value on select tag using onclick function to google chart datatable

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

**select tag**

I've got the function  *select_value()*

```
<select id="data" onChange="select_value()">
  <option value="['car', 7],['jeep', 2],['taxi', 1]">aaa</option>     
  <option value="['car', 9],['taxi', 1]">bbb</option>   
</select>
```

I can't call the *select_value()* function inside google chart...

**my script**

```
function select_value() {
  var stringPie = document.getElementById('data').value;
}
```

**google chart**

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Cartype');
data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');

var stringPie = document.getElementById('data').value; // <==
var arrPie = eval("[" + stringPie + "]");
data.addRows(arrPie);
```

the chart always stuck on the first option value of select tag...

Comment: Please don't use *eval*, replace `eval("[" + stringPie + "]");` with `[stringPie];`.

Comment: @RobG - wont work on that sir

Comment: You have a function called *selectPie_value*, the listener calls a different function: *select_value()*, so it's not calling that function. I don't see any element with the ID *selectPie*. Your first comment seems to contain additional code. If it should be in the question, edit the question and add it in an appropriate place.

Comment: sorry sir... now i finished edit.... can you please help me with it... I want to display in google chart my selected data from dropdown list....

Comment: Please don't call me *sir*.

Answer (score 1):

The select element contains values like:

```
"['car', 7],['jeep', 2],['taxi', 1]"
```

that appear to be data for multiple rows. You are converting it to an array using *eval*, which is a very poor strategy.

To avoid *eval*, convert the string to an appropriate structure using *split* or *JSON.parse*, e.g.

Markup:

```
<select id="data" onChange="select_value(this)">
  <option value="['car', 7],['jeep', 2],['taxi', 1]">aaa</option>     
  <option value="['car', 9],['taxi', 1]">bbb</option>   
</select>
```

Script:

```
// Passing this from the listener gives direct access to the
// element on which the event was triggered
function select_value(element) {

  // JSON can't contain single quotes, so replace them with double
  var stringPie = element.value.replace(/'/g,'"');

  // Convert the values to an array of arrays:
  var arrPie = JSON.parse('[' + stringPie + ']');

  // Add the rows only if there are values to add:
  if (arrPie.length) {
    data.addRows(arrPie);
  }
}
```

*JSON.parse* is handy because like *eval*, you can easily specify different types (e.g. string, number) but avoid many of the pitfalls of *eval*.

Untested, but should work.